# ScrollView won`t scroll after object is placed

Tags: scrollview

I guess this will be embracing but i start to get really frustrated:
I`m writing code for the first time so please help.
Working with X-Code, objective-C.

I would like to be able to scroll on my App-Pages, so i added a UIScrollView:

```
@interface HeggViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

}

@implementation HeggViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

It works fine until i add something. Button, Picture, label......
Can i just add buttons to the ScrollView or do i need to place something else first

What have i done wrong?

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your code to add the objects, but if you do the following, it must work fine:

```
// Create your image
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(79, 20, 100, 100)];
// Add the image to the scrollview
[scroller addSubview:image];
```